# Mobile Safari auto focus on text input

Tags: focus, mobile-safari, safari

I would like to focus on a text input field immediately on page load. However the following code, that works on desktop browsers, doesn't work on mobile Safari (on iOS 6).:

```
  <input type="text" name="q" class="search" id="focusme" />

  ...

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){var a=document.getElementById("focusme");a.focus();}
  </script>
```

I have tried to implement several suggested fixes for this. However I haven't been able to get it working. It does display the CSS changes to the field when it is in focus, however the keyboard is not brought up.

I suspect this may be due to my currently very limited understanding of JavaScript, but I think it may still be a bug in Safari.

*The question:*

**In Safari on iOS 6, Do you know of any way to auto focus on a text input field on page load?**

Thank you for your help :-)

Update:

The page does have jquery and mobile-jquery available, if they need to be used.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for trying: http://jsfiddle.net/pXvAD/

Answer (score 0):

Why using JavaScript? `<input type="text" autofocus />` should do it!

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately. Had the same behavior of the CSS showing the input box as selected, but the keyboard not actually being up.

Comment: OK, finally found some info about that: "By design, some focus() events in Mobile Safari are ignored. A lot of sites would do focus() unnecessarily and bringing up the keyboard is slow/intrusive." See: http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard And here: http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/02-autofocus.html

Comment: Cool, thanks for linking to that. In the instance I'm using it I personally think it does make usability sense - the user will being clicking on a button to search, that goes to a new page with the search bar (i.e. input field) on it - so they will always want to tap on the search bar (theoretically).

Comment: I agree, it would make sense in your use case.